# Replacing NA values with items in a list

Tags: r, na

I have a data frame where with 22 columns, and some where around 600 rows. In one of the columns I have a bunch of NA values, and I want to replace those with items from a list so I can use that column as ID's however I have yet to find a solution

The simple `replace(data$Tag_Number, is.na(data$Tag_Number, pse.id))`
does not work `(where pse.id = (5000:6000))`.

I also tried:

```
>for(i in length(data[,1])){
  if(is.na(data$Tag_Number[i])==TRUE){
    new.id = pse.id[[i]]
    data$Tag_Number[i] = new.id
  }
}
```

It seems that R really does not want me writing over the NA value. 
any ideas?

Comment: what kind of error are you getting?

Comment: I'm getting Warning message:
  Warning message:
In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, i, value = c(247L, 251L, 110L, 107L, 105L,  :
  invalid factor level, NA generated

Comment: You have a few issues with your `for` loop. (1) `length(data[,1])` should be `1:length(data[,1])` otherwise it's only changing the last value every iteration. (2) `==TRUE` is not necessary because `is.na` already returns a logical and `if` will only process the statement when TRUE anyway (3) have you initialized the vector `new.id`? Please provide something reproducible. This can be easily vectorized and done without a loop

Comment: I can't seem to reproduce the same error however I can broaden the questions.                                                                x= c(1:10)
    y= c(30,31,NA,41,46,NA,55,NA,66,80)
    df = as.data.frame(cbind(x,y))
    New = (1000:2000)  How do I replace the NA values with values form the New list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see any problem just using the regular assignment operator.  To answer your more general statement of the question:

```
> x <- 1:10
> y <- c(30, 31, NA, 41, 46, NA, 55, NA, 66, 80)
> df <- data.frame(x, y)
> New <- 1000:2000
> df$y[is.na(df$y)] <- New[1:sum(is.na(df$y))] 
> df
    x    y
1   1   30
2   2   31
3   3 1000
4   4   41
5   5   46
6   6 1001
7   7   55
8   8 1002
9   9   66
10 10   80
```

Make sure the number of elements of `New` that you are assigning is equal to the number of `NA` values being overwritten.

Comment: When I use that where 'df=data' and 'y=Tag_Number' I get an error that says 'Warning message:
In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, is.na(data$Tag_Number), value = c(247L,  :
  invalid factor level, NA generated'

Comment: Your problem is that Tag_Number is of class "factor" and it is not expecting the values in `pse.id`.  R is happy to convert many things to factors that we do not want to be factors, causing subsequent bugs because factors require special handling.  It was an unfortunate early design decision that can't be changed now.   Specify `stringsAsFactors=FALSE` when creating the data frame and/or change the class of that column using `as.numeric()` or `as.character()`, depending on which type of data it is.